# LESS CSS, @import path from variable

Tags: css, less

I want to declare a variable with the path to the library:

```
@libPath: "any/path/to/lib";
```

And use it in `@import`. Something like this:

```
@import "@{libPath}/file.less";
```

And I see the result after processing:

```
@import url("@{libPath}/file.less");
```

No such possibility or am I doing something wrong?

*Thanks.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FWIW [**this is a bug** in less.js](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/410) that’s been discussed for way over a year now. There are at least two attempts to fix this but one requires large changes to the public API and has consequently been rejected. [The other approach only works partially](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/pull/1108).

On the other hand, [lessphp supports this without problem now](http://leafo.net/lessphp/); I have no idea whether dotless does.

Comment: since version 1.4 it should partial work when your variables have been declared in the root or current scope, see: http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-import-statements

Answer (score 0):

It isn't supported in less.js or dotless so I assume less PHP is the same. It might not be hard to add, why don't you add a feature request.

Also what is the problem you are trying to solve? Maybe it can be solved a better way.