# Using variables in import directive for LESS

Tags: css, less

I can't find a way to use variables in `import` directive for LESS.

I have got a @cdnUri variable which gets it's value from JavaScript:

```
@cdnUri: `window.cdnUri`;
```

`cdnUri` can be `http://localhost/cdn` in development mode or `http://cdn.example.com` in production mode.

What i want is importing other LESS file with this Urls prepended. Like this:

```
@import "@{cdnUri}/shared/twitter-bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"
```

But it gives me this error because it doesn't parse the variables from url.

```
Couldn't load http://wordy/ui/frontend/themes/default2/ui/css/@{cdnUri}/ui/shared/js/twitter-bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less (404)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but LESS imports are always relative to the current file, so it's not possible to import from another domain.

Comment: I believe that you can now use the tilde-quote escape pattern to load files without relative paths. i.e. ~"http://www.abc.com"

Comment: `@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css")` seems to work for me...

Answer (score 1):

It is a known less.js bug. It was a year to partially fix it.

Here is what you want:

[LESS CSS, @import path from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676628/less-css-import-path-from-variable)

Talk about this bug.

https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/pull/1108

And here are the new sources.